# Unpivot Csv Files with changing schemas on linux

Tags: csv

From one of our customers, we receive x number of csv files on our sftp server. The files usually vary in terms of header names, column count and of course row count (usually somewhere between a couple of thousand and a couple of million rows, file size do for the most of them not exceed 350 mb). Currently we process all the files through ssis using some custom c# script.

What I want to accomplish is this...Move the entire process to linux (our sftp server), in order to shorten the data-flow and the pre-processing time.

This may very well be a trivial task for a lot of you guys, but I cant say I belong to that category...having no real experience developing on linux.

So how to do this, are there any feasible solutions, in regards to time efficiency, memory consumption etc...

Csv files could look like this, except the number of user columns always change:

eg. Filename: userdata.csv

```
Question; user1; user2; user3; user4
How old are you; 20; 22; 45; 54
How tall are you; 186; 176; 166; 195
```

And the output I'm after looks like this:

```
Question; Value; User; Filename
How old are you; 20; user1; userdata
How old are you; 22; user2; userdata
How old are you; 45; user3; userdata
How old are you; 54; user4; userdata
How tall are you; 186; user1; userdata
How tall are you; 176; user2; userdata
How tall are you; 166; user3; userdata
How tall are you; 195; user4; userdata
```

Suggestions, advice...anything is most welcome.

**Update:**

Just to elaborate on the input/output specifics..

1. **input.csv** (The result of a questionnaire)

   - 2 questions, "How old are you" and "How tall are you" answered by 4 users, "user1", "user2", "user3" and "user4".
   - For the purpose of this example "user1" - "user4" is used.
   - In our live data the users real names are used.
   - The number of user columns will vary depending on how many participated in the questionnaire.
2. **output.csv**

   - The header row is change to display 4 static fields: Question, Value, User and Filename.
   - Instead of having a row per question as in the input file, we need a row per user.
   - The Filename column should hold the name of the input file without extension.

character encoding is UTF-8 and the separator is semicolon. Qualifiers are not used.

Comment: You need to specify _exactly_ the format of the input (and output) files.

Comment: The mapping from input to output values is unclear from your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit of reading in here and a lot of trial and error, it seems i have a working solution. Though it might not be pretty and leaves room for improvement, this is what it got:

A scheduled bash script which loops a filename array and passes the individual filenames to the awk script.

orgFile.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

shopt -s nullglob
fileList=(*.csv)

for i in "${fileList[@]}"; do
   awk -v filename="$i" -f newFile.awk $i
done
```

newFile.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function fname(file, a, n)
{
    n = split(file, a, ".")
    return a[1]
}

BEGIN{
    FS = ";"
    fn = "done_" filename
    print "Question;Value;User;ID" > fn
}
{
    if (NR == 1)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        {
            headers[i] = $i
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++ )
        {
            if (i > 1)
            {
                print $1 FS $i FS headers[i] FS fname(filename) >> fn
            }
        }
    }
}
```